# Powershell ,CSV and Checklistbox

Tags: powershell

maybe someone can help me with this. I am trying to generate a checklist-box from a CSV just using the headers. Then only export-cvs with the titles and data in that column i checked

the header and the amount of fields will change with the different CVS i use, so i cant hard code it.

currently i use the follow code that populates the headers in the checklistbox, but it generates all on one line

```
Get-Content $list | select -First 1
```

shows below

Name,species,age,breed,shots

what i would like it to do is generate the names right next to a checkbox like this

Name
Species
age
breed
shots

then i can move on to getting the check fields to export-CSV. thanks ahead of time

## # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # #

the out come is program is exactly what i am looking for thank you. but the problem that i have now is to try and integrate it in to the program i was hoping it was a one line fixer the whole problem is pretty large, but this is the part i am having issues with. here is the original code

This part would load the CSV

```
$MasterBtn_Click={
if($openfile.ShowDialog() -eq 'OK')
{
    $MasterTxT.Text = $openfile.FileName
    $MasterLT = $MasterTxT.Text
}

$labelFormHeaders.Text = Get-Content $MasterLT  | select -First 1 
}
```

This part compares and export my choices

```
$buttonStartProcess_Click={

$script:CancelLoop = $false
$buttonCancelProcess.Enabled = $true

$this.Enabled = $false

$progressbar1.Value = 0

for($i = 0; $i -lt $progressbar1.Maximum; $i++)
{
    #----------------------------------------


    $col1 = $textbox1.text
    $col2 = $textbox2.text
    $col3 = $textbox3.text
    $col4 = $textbox4.text
    $col5 = $textbox5.text
    $col6 = $textbox6.text

    $list =  $EventLt
    $Data =  $MasterLT


$Userlist = Import-csv -path $list
$userData = Import-Csv -Path $Data 
$UserOutput = @()

$Result = "C:\Temp\Results1.csv"


ForEach ($name in $UserList)
{

    $userMatch = $UserData | where {$_.ID -eq $name.usernames}
    If($userMatch)
    {
        # Process the data

        $UserOutput += New-Object PsObject -Property @{ID     =$name.usernames; "$col1" = $userMatch.$col1; "$col2" =$userMatch.$col2; "$col3" =$userMatch.$col3;"$col4" =$userMatch.$col4;"$col5" =$userMatch.$col5;"$col6" =$userMatch.$col6} #

    }
    else
    {
        $UserOutput += New-Object PsObject -Property @{ID =$name.usernames; "$col1" ="NA";"$col2" ="NA";"$col3" ="NA";"$col4" ="NA";"$col5" ="NA";"$col6" ="NA"}
    }


}
$UserOutput | Select-Object "ID","$col1","$col2","$col3","$col4","$col5","$col6" | Export-Csv -Path $Result -NoTypeInformation

    sleep -Milliseconds 200



    [System.Windows.Forms.Application]::DoEvents()

    if($script:CancelLoop -eq $true)
    {

        $progressbar1.Value = 0

        break;
    }
    r
    $progressbar1.PerformStep() 
}


$this.Enabled = $true
$buttonCancelProcess.Enabled = $false
}
```

currently i have a bunch of textboxes, that i would have to manual enter the headers. i would like to eliminate that and have a generated checkbox list that when a box is check and i hit the "$ buttonstartprocess" it will pull those options from the checkbox and give me the rows i want. hope i dont lose anyone. thank again.

Comment: It sounds like Name,species,... is a series of field names (column names).  Is that what you are trying to find out from the CSV file?  If so, I have a tool that I'll post that solves a slightly different problem, but contains code that you may be able to adapt.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

```
#get list of header
$headerlist=import-csv C:\temp\resul2.csv  | Get-member -MemberType 'NoteProperty' | Select-Object -ExpandProperty 'Name'

[reflection.assembly]::loadwithpartialname("System.Windows.Forms") | Out-Null
[reflection.assembly]::loadwithpartialname("System.Drawing") | Out-Null

#create form
$Form = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form    
$Form.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(600,400) 
$Form.text ="Form test" 

#create groupbox for list checkbox
$groupBox = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.GroupBox
$groupBox.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(240,20)  
$groupBox.text = "You checkbox items" 
$Form.Controls.Add($groupBox)

$Checkboxes += New-Object System.Windows.Forms.CheckBox
$Checkboxes.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(10,20) 

#add checkbox list 
$Checkboxes = @()
$y = 20
foreach ($a in $headerlist)
{    
    $Checkbox = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.CheckBox
    $Checkbox.Text = $a
    $Checkbox.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(10,$y) 
    $y += 30
    $groupBox.Controls.Add($Checkbox) 
    $Checkboxes += $Checkbox
}
$groupBox.size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(200,(40*$checkboxes.Count))

#show result 
$form.ShowDialog()| Out-Null
```

Comment: the out come is program is exactly what i am looking for thank you. but the problem that i have now is to try and integrate it in to the program i was hoping it was a one line fixer the whole problem is pretty large, but this is the part i am having issues with